# searching for multiple occurrence of a text and changing another text in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new at vba. I am searching for a string in excel can also be multiple occurrence and then for each occurrence changing another text if this string is found. but my code is going into infinite loop. How can i achieve that? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub PRODA_Replace_IfNDM_Click()
    Dim FindWord As String, Found As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim rslt As Range
    FindWord = "/*_NDM*"
    Set Found = Sheets("PRODA").Cells.Find(What:=FindWord, _
                                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                           lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                           searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                           searchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                           MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = Found.Address
        Do
            Set rslt = Sheets("PRODA").Cells.Find(What:="OWNER:*", _
                                                  After:=Found, _
                                                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                  lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                  searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                  searchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                  MatchCase:=False)
            Sheets("PRODA").Cells.Replace What:=rslt, _
                                          Replacement:="OWNER:chrndm", _
                                          lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                          searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                          MatchCase:=False, _
                                          searchFormat:=False, _
                                          ReplaceFormat:=False
            MsgBox Found
            If Found Is Nothing Then
                GoTo endFinding
            End If
            Set Found = Cells.FindNext(After:=Found)
        Loop While Not Found Is Nothing And firstAddress <> Found.Address
    End If
endFinding:
    MsgBox "changed successfully"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it..Please do help me..I am stuck in the loop as the variable "Found" above is changing its value due to which its going into infinite loop.

Comment: You are looping until you get to a cell which contains "OWNER:*" **AND** is the first cell that contains "/*_NDM*" - do you have a cell that matches both those criteria?  What is your code trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to first search for "/*_NDM*" for each occurrence of that string  I am trying to replace the OWNER with new value.

Comment: So you are saying that if "/*_NDM*" appears **anywhere** on the worksheet, **all** occurrences of "OWNER" in the **entire** worksheet need to be changed?

Comment: In the worksheet if "/*_NDM*" is present then for each occurrence OWNER needs to be changed..for example if NDM is present in 13th line then OWNER present below that needs to be changed..again if NDM is found in 20th line the OWNER below 20th line needs to be changed...for every occurrence of NDM a OWNER will be present below it which needs to be changed...

Comment: You can't use two nested Find() calls like that: your FindNext repeats the "OWNER" search, not the original "NDM"  See for eaxample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011389/multple-find-requests-in-vba-excel-find-within-a-find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that, for every occurrence of the `findword` string, the next occurrence of `"OWNER:*"` is the one to be changed, the following code will hopefully work:

```
Private Sub PRODA_Replace_IfNDM_Click()
    Dim FindWord As String, Found As Range
    Dim ownerCell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim rslt As Range
    FindWord = "/*_NDM*"
    With Sheets("PRODA")
        Set Found = .Cells.Find(What:=FindWord, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                searchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = Found.Address
            Do
                Set ownerCell = .Cells.Find(What:="OWNER:*", _
                                            After:=Found, _
                                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                            lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                            searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                            searchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=False)
                If ownerCell Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "No corresponding owner for word found at " & Found.Address
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                ownerCell.Value = "OWNER:chrndm"
                'Can't do FindNext, because we did a different Find
                Set Found = .Cells.Find(What:=FindWord, _
                                        After:=Found, _
                                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        lookAt:=xlPart, _
                                        searchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        searchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False)
                If Found.Address = firstAddress Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            MsgBox "changed successfully"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tested with some dummy data which hopefully replicates what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much...This code works.. :)...I have one last doubt what was the issue with FindNext??If we use use Find two different times and storing that result in a different variables then FindNext should work or am I wrong?

Comment: @SachinPanda - `Find` returns on object but has no clue that you have saved the returned object in a variable, or whether you have simply taken the object to get its `.Address` property, or anything else.  It definitely doesn't know **which** variable you have saved the result in.  So `FindNext` only refers to the properties that you passed to the previous `Find`.