# Loop doesnt work anymore after nested IF statements

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to vba coding, as in started learning it yesterday new, and i have a question on what i am doing wrong here.

I am trying to write a code that finds a certain word on a certain range, checks the values on adjacent cells, looks for those values in another range, and if not found, do some actions, and then goes back to the first range to look for the next match.

ive managed to get the loop working  before inserting the second .find, but once it is added it breaks the loop? it gives me the `runtime error 91: object variable or with block variable not set.

i have tried altering the variables' data types from `Range` to `String` and from `String` to `Range`

i have tried `Set variable =` and just `variable =` for the variables

i have released the second `.Find()` variables before it reaches the loop

i have moved so many lines around

again, i am very new to this, and if anybody could give me a hand id be very grateful

the line in question is `Loop While cred.Address <> firstcred` and it works fine in the first subroutine, but returns an error in the second one

```
sub subname1()

Dim credeb As Range
Dim cred As Range
Dim firstcred As String
Dim nome1 As Range
Dim data1 As Range

Set credeb = Range("credeb")   
Set cred = credeb.find("crédito")

If cred Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Final

Else
    firstcred = cred.Address

    Do
        cred.Activate

        Set nome1 = cred.Offset(0, -2) 
        Set data1 = cred.Offset(0, -1) 

        nome1.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        data1.Interior.Color = vbYellow

        Set cred = credeb.FindNext(cred)

    Loop While cred.Address <> firstcred

End If

Final:
End Sub

______________________

Sub subname2()

Dim credeb As Range
Dim cred As Range
Dim firstcred As String
Dim nome1 As Range
Dim data1 As Range
Dim nome2 As Range
Dim nome11 As Range

Set credeb = Range("credeb")   'nome da tabela credito ou debito
Set cred = credeb.find("crédito")
Set nome2 = Range("nome2")     'nome da tabela de nomes do credito

If cred Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Final

Else
    firstcred = cred.Address

    Do
        cred.Activate

        Set nome1 = cred.Offset(0, -2)  
        Set data1 = cred.Offset(0, -1)   
        Set nome11 = nome2.find(nome1)


        If nome11 Is Nothing Then
            nome1.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            data1.Interior.Color = vbYellow

            Set nome1 = Nothing
            Set data1 = Nothing
            Set nome11 = Nothing

        End If

        Set cred = credeb.FindNext(cred)

    Loop While cred.Address <> firstcred

End If
Final:
End Sub
```

the above code returns the Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. how do I fix this code so it performs normally?

Comment: The `Find` object is global and stores the last used parameters. You can observe them after you stop the macro and press Ctrl+F on the sheet. So the inner `nome2.find(nome1)` overwrites the "what" parameter, so `credeb.FindNext(cred)` will be looking for the next `nome1`, not next `"crédito"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multple find requests in vba Excel (Find within a Find)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20011389/11683)

Comment: Because of the exact problem @GSerg brought up, instead of using `FindNext(cred)`, instead use `Set cred = credeb.Find("crédito", cred)` for that line.

Comment: Additionally, the solution @GSerg points out will also work for this.

Comment: @GSerg -   Seems like I'm repeating myself  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Running Find in a loop can make your main code difficult to maintain, and if you need to do that in multiple places then the best approach is to factor it out into a separate function.

Eg. you can do something like this:

```
sub subname1()

    Dim hits as Collection, hit 

    Set hits = FindAll(Range("credeb"), "crédito")

    if hits.Count > 0 then
        for each hit in hits
            hit.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1,2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        next hit
    end if

End Sub
```

Function to find all matches:

```
'return all cells in "rng" which match "val", as a Collection
'  (edit the Find method parameters as needed)
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection

    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    'best to be explicit about exactly what you want Find to do...
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```